# How can I send Info from HC05 (arduino) to Android over Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I only need to send ONE value to trigger a function on an android app, but am unable to figure out how to use the HC05 to send values.
This is what I have curreently. Thanks in advance for any help

```
const int analogInPin = A0;  
// Analog input pin that the potentiometer is attached to

const int analogOutPin = 13; 
// Analog output pin that the LED is attached to

int sensorValue = 0;
// value read from the pot
int outputValue = 0;        
// value output to the PWM (analog out)

void setup() {
 // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // read the analog in value:
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);
  // map it to the range of the analog out:
  outputValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  // change the analog out value:
  analogWrite(analogOutPin, outputValue);

  // print the results to the serial monitor:
  Serial.print("sensor = ");
  Serial.print(sensorValue);
  if(sensorValue < 30 ) {Serial.println("TRIGGERED");
  Serial.end();
  };

  Serial.print("\t output = ");
  Serial.println(outputValue);

  // wait 100 milliseconds before the next loop
  // for the analog-to-digital converter to settle
  // after the last reading:
  delay(100);`enter code here`
}
```